# callback function in custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to call a custom function after another completes. Lots of jquery includes a way to do a call back, like when an animation completes you can just give it another function as a last parameter. But is there anyway to string together `function1(params, function1(){alert('2');})` or something? I honestly have no idea how it would look.

Thank you

Comment: You might also want to do some research on promises and AOP, as overuse of callbacks leads to ugly code.

Comment: btw there's a lot of "function1" in your question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a function pointer with something like:

```
var yourCallback = function() {
    alert('2');
}
```

You can think of it as an object containing the function itself (not its return value).  Since it is an object, you can pass it around to other functions.

Then pass that to the function you are calling as an argument (do not invoke it with `()`, as that would pass its return value):

```
function1(params, yourCallback);
```

Finally, in function1, invoke your callback when you need it:

```
function function1(args, callback) {
    //Some code
    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying wrap my head around this answer, and make a working fiddle. Would it be too much to ask for you to make one though, so that I can see it in action. Thank you so much.

Comment: @thomas I've also updated my post with (hopefully helpful) information.

Comment: thanks! this is actually more understandable than I thought it might be. If I wanted to add a third function to be called last, so I could do alerts of 1, 2, and 3, would I then `var yourCallback = function(secondCallback)`? Of course I'm trying it on my own, just a lot to juggle mentally..

Comment: @thomas, actually by passing that argument, you would be invoking the function, and thus passing its return value.  So you'd need to pass the arguments and the callback functions as separate params.  Does that make sense?  It's a little tricky when you first see it.  Another thing you could do is wrap the callback (with the parameter) in an anonymous function, such as: `function() { var yourCallback = function(secondCallback); }` so that the value returned IS your function.

Comment: yes, thank you for the additional information. my fiddle is not working with the three however. do you mind taking a look. http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/WfKx2/1/

Comment: @thomas I have to run to lunch quick, but in your example, I think you need to invoke the secondCallback IN your first one.  Otherwise they get run one after the other.

Comment: gotcha. I will try my best! thank you for all your guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically the pattern you're asking for is:

```
function myFunctionNeedsACallback(param1, callback) {
    //do stuff with param1
    if(typeof callback === "function"){
        callback.call(yourThisParam, anyOtherParams);
    }
}
```

While this is a useful pattern... overuse will lead to ugly, untestable, and unmaintainable code. Use with discretion.

Your example would work just fine:

```
myFunctionNeedsACallback(param, function() { alert('2'); });

//will alert 2 after running the rest of the contents of the function
```

**EDIT**

To address thomas's situation:

```
function ajaxCall1(){
    return $.ajax(/*your parameters NO SUCCESS CALLBACK NEEDED*/);
}

function ajaxCall2(){
    return $.ajax(/*your parameters NO SUCCESS CALLBACK NEEDED*/);
}

function ajaxCall3(){
    return $.ajax(/*your parameters NO SUCCESS CALLBACK NEEDED*/);
}

$.when(ajaxCall1(), ajaxCall2(), ajaxCall3()).then(function(results1, results2, results3) {
    //do stuff with all 3 results without "nesting" things
});
```

Comment: What not-ugly alternative do you recommend then for such a problem? I can only think of events, which would lead to even more complicated code. I personally think it's a very elegant solution, especially if you're already using jquery which is full of this pattern.

Comment: @Andy: __Overuse__ will lead to ugly code. Callbacks in and of themselves are not a problem. It'd be horrible to not have them. However, I see people doing stuff like (psuedo) `ajax(ajax(ajax(/*do something with all 3 results */)))` and it just hurts. As Christophe said in the comments on the question, Promises make that kind of code much easier to work with..and read

Comment: @BLSully the functions I'm calling do use ajax. three calls actually. What you're talking about in the psuedo you wrote is sorta what I'm trying to avoid. Each subsequent call happening in the success callback of the ajax function. Do you have a tutorial that shows how I can use promises to fire off 3 or 4 functions using it? Thank you very much

Comment: This is getting clearer. I'd like to keep my success functions just because I have a json template in each one and it makes it easier for me if the ajax calls are together with the functionality that does something with their returned data. Will a success callback break this at all? Can I do `$.when(ajaxCall1(), ajaxCall2(), ajaxCall3()).then(function(){alert('all three ajax functions definitely complete now!');}`

Comment: @thomas: you can still have success callbacks in the individual ajax calls. The `when` will still get the results too. I've done that before and it does work just fine. And yes, your example should work ok

Comment: But here, the alert that is it complete is firing before the success callbacks write their returned data to the page. http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/mWAnk/  And it is all at once, without the delay specified specified in the ajax object. Any idea what's going on there? Thank you.

Comment: @thomas: I don't think there are any guarantees to which will fire first...the `success` callbacks or the `then`. Are you sure you need to implement the `success` callbacks though? can it be done in the `then`? could it be done in an `always`? jquery has lots of functionality for `Deferred` objects

Comment: I figured out what happened. I missed the addition of the `return` before `$.ajax`. Yeah, there is a lot of functionality ehre. the oddest of which seems to be that the object returned by `results1` is a string (`"success"`) and an object. I'm sure I'll be posting more about it today as I try to figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSomething(arg1, callback){
    // bla bla bla
    callback();
}
```

Comment: and callback() can be declared elsewhere on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You'd structure your function something like this:

```
function one(x, y, z, callback) {
   // do operations here

   callback();
}
```

Then, since functions are objects you could pass in a function through the callback parameter, IE:

```
one(1, 2, 3, function(){alert('hello');});
```

Or

```
var func = function() { alert('hello'); };
one(1, 2, 3, func);
```

Or

```
function func() {
  alert('hello');
}

one(1, 2, 3, func);
```

Answer (score 0):

While callbacks are convenient, overuse can lead to ugly and unmaintainable code. Besides standard callbacks shown in other answers, you might want to look at other patterns like deferred/promises and AOP.

In jQuery, promises are implemented with [when() and then()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

[requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) is also a good startpoint.

Comment: can you show me an example of how this callback functionality can be implemented with `when()` and `then()`. I have tried to read about them before and thought they were used mainly for complicated ajax stuff. Also, i remember they, themselves, being quite complicated heheh

Comment: @thomas correct, and you'll certainly rely on a library to implement promises. They work for any asynchronous action, not just ajax (if your functions are not asynchronous, then you don't need a callback). Definitely worth considering if in practice you need to chain multiple callbacks.