# calling three subsequent callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to apply what I learned about callback functions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421211/callback-function-in-custom-function/13421257#comment18342656_13421257) I made to extend to 3 functions, but am having some trouble getting things working. Can someone please help me understand how I can get these three functions to fire in sequence?

```
var yourCallback = function(args, second) {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').append(args);
    }, 800);

    second('3-');


}

var yourSecondCallback = function(args) {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').append(args);
    }, 800);
}

function function1(args, callback, yourSecondCallback) {
    $('body').append(args);
    if (callback) {
        callback('2-');
    }

}


function1('1-' , yourCallback);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/WfKx2/3/

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your `second` function?

Comment: You've only supplied one callback in your call to `function1`. Also, you need to pass the second callback to `yourCallback` so that `yourCallback` can call `yourSecondCallback`. Daisy chaining callbacks gets complicated quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest the callbacks to get them to call in order.

```
var yourCallback = function(args, second) {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').append(args);
        second('3-');
    }, 800);
}

var yourSecondCallback = function(args) {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').append(args);
    }, 800);
}

function function1(args, callback) {
    $('body').append(args);
    if (callback) {
        callback('2-', yourSecondCallback);
    }

}


function1('1-' , yourCallback);​
```

[Here's your altered fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blesh/WfKx2/4/)

Comment: I feel like I was close to this. But just couldn't quite get my mind round it. Endless thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: Yeah, you were pretty close. All I did was move a couple of things around.

Answer (score 0):

If your first argument and only is going to be an input for all the callbacks then this code can be used for unlimited arguments

```
var yourCallback = function(args, second) {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').append(args + ' first function');
    }, 800);

}

var yourSecondCallback = function(args) {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').append(args + ' second function');
    }, 800);
}

function function1(args) {
    var callbacks = arguments.length - 1;
    for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof(arguments[i] == 'function')) {
            arguments[i](arguments[0]);
        }
    }
}


function1('1-', yourCallback, yourSecondCallback);​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8squF/

Comment: what does registering as deferred entail?

Answer (score 0):

Your function names confuse me, so I'm just going to make some up to demonstrate a simple approach:

```
function1('-1', function(){
    secondCallback(...);
    thirdCallback(...);
    ...
});
```

Any reason a simple approach like that won't work for you?

Comment: yeah, the names have got a little redundant. in your example, will SecondCallback and thirdCallBack necessarily get fired in that order, even if they are ajax requests that will take different amounts of time?

Comment: No. And that is pertinent information you need to explicitly call out in your question - I see no AJAX requests anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do here, but when you do this in `function1`:

```
callback('2-');
```

You are calling this method:

```
var yourCallback = function(args, second)
```

But you are not providing a value for `second`, so you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function, **mainMethod**, that is calling three callback functions.

**mainFunction** the first callback function(one) will be called and the first parameter will be passed into it.

**one** will pass the second parameter into the second callback function (two).

**two** will pass the third parameter into the last callback function (three).

**three** will just log the last parameter that was passed into it.

```js
function mainFunction(callback1, callback2, callback3){

      var first_parameter = "ONE"
      callback1(first_parameter);
}


function one(a){

         console.log("one: " + a);
         var second_parameter = "TWO"
         two(second_parameter);
}

function two(b){

         console.log("two: " + b);
         var third_parameter = "THREE";
         three(third_parameter);
}

function three(c){

         console.log("three: " + c);
}


mainFunction(one, two, three);
```